# Click on a thumbnail, an image in a div changes

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to do the following:

- a row with a couple of thumbnails that, when clicked, change an image in a main div

What would be the best way to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="changeImage" rel="1"><img class="thumb" src="image1_thumb.jpg" /></a>
<div id="imageBox">&nbsp;</div>
```

and the jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeImage').click(function(){
        var $rel = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox").html("<img src='image" + $rel + ".jpg' />");
    })
})

</script>
```

but it's not working.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeImage').click(function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox").html("<img src='image" + rel + ".jpg' />");
    })
});
```

- Your original code is targeting an attribute of an anchor inside the 'changeImage' anchor.  You were going one level too deep.
- I also removed an unnecessary usage of $ with 'rel' variable.
- And lastly, added a semicolon at the very end.

Also, I'd suggest you have a placeholder image (inside 'imageBox') and just change its 'src' attribute (instead of manipulating the DOM so much for no reason).  Something like this:

```
$("#imageBox img").attr('src', 'image' + rel + '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeImage').click(function(){
        var $rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox").html("<img src='image" + $rel + ".jpg' />");
    })
})

</script>
```

Because you clicked on the `<a>`, `$(this)` is the element with the rel attribute... The `.find('a')` was searching for a child element within the link you clicked.

Your code would have worked with this html:

```
<a href="#" id="changeImage">
    <a href="#" rel="1"><img class="thumb" src="image1_thumb.jpg" /></a>
</a>
<div id="imageBox">&nbsp;</div>
```

Which is obviously redundant...

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, this works. It's a similar answer to Kon's, I chose his just for the omission of $ :)

Answer (score 0):

`#changeImage` should be `.changeImage`

Comment: But there are no elements with a .changeImage CSS class.

Comment: I should have elaborated. change the "id='changeImage'" to "class='changeImage'"