# click on image thumbnail, image will be loaded into a container div in big size

Tags: jquery

I have the next code with some thumbnails:

```
<div class="gallery-wrap">
    <div class="gallery galleryid-45" id="gallery-1">
        <dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon"> <a href="http://somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/ring-wedding.jpg"><img height="66" width="67" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="ring-wedding-67x66.jpg"></a> </dt>
        </dl>
        <dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon"> <a href="http://somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/wedding-rings.jpg"><img height="66" width="67" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="wedding-rings-67x66.jpg"></a> </dt>
        </dl>
        <dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon"> <a href="http://somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/wedding-ring-test-31.jpg"><img height="66" width="67" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="wedding-ring-test-31-67x66.jpg"></a> </dt>
        </dl>
        <br style="clear: both">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imageBox">&nbsp;</div>
```

It's a gallery generated by wordpress with the built in gallery function which was customized a little bit by me.

I would like whenever I click on a thumbnail, the image to change in `#imageBox`. I would like to test two situations,

1. when page loads and #imageBox to be empty,
2. when page loads and #imageBox to have included already the first image according the first thumbnail :)

I know there is a solution ([Click on a thumbnail, an image in a div changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012321/)) but is not working for me and I think it is because a different HTML markup structure.

Does anyone have an idea how to start/solve this issue?

Comment: that's right. i appreciate anyones help, but it would be a lie from my part to accept an answer which didn't helped me. but also i thank you for telling this, so i remembered the latest answers to accept them. sooner or later i will accept them for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".gallery-item a").click(function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $("#imageBox").empty().append( 
    $("<img>", {src: this.href})
  );
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/kq9bp/1/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I think your suggestion makes sense, but in my environment it is not working :( When clicking on thumbnail the image is loaded in a new empty page like usual. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.4" type="text/javascript"></script>` is the jquery is loaded by my wordpress :|

Comment: @TheHun: Have you verified that your JavaScript is even running? Check at the developer console of your browser for any error messages.

Comment: yeah, javascript is running, i am using a temporary solution with no jquery, only simple javascript image swap.

Comment: @TheHun: Well, what can I say. The sample runs, as you can see, so the error is somewhere on your end.

Comment: yeah, that is for sure, thanks for your help. maybe because it's friday... that's why i don't see the reason :)